# Explanation of iCloud Containers

Tags: ios, file, swift4, icloud

I am thoroughly confused.  I thought I understood iCloud containers, but apparently not.

I have an app that creates a bunch of files in an iCloud container that I use to backup and restore. In a separate app I created a different container. Both apps seemed to use the same container and on some devices and/or simulators, the container is named like the 1st app, some like the 2nd app, but at least the files showed up when I looked on iCloud.com, the Files app, or the local copy on my Mac. I could live with that, but then I needed to change the name of my app and just created a new project and imported all the source files and created a new container named after the new app.

The new app seems to write the backup files without error, but there doesn't seem to be any trace of the files in iCloud, Files, or the cached copy on my Mac, but when I go to a different simulator instance and run my app and try to restore the backup, it works, yet the files aren't visible in the aforementioned places.

Can anyone explain what is going on behind the scenes and how to make the files/container visible?

Following is the code used to write the file... At the end I read the text back from the same file just to ensure it is really there, but that is just for debugging.

```
func toJSON(objects: [NSManagedObject], file: String)
{
        if let dir = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        {
            let ddir = dir.appendingPathComponent("Data", isDirectory: true)

            do
            {
                if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: ddir.path)
                {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: ddir, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                debugPrint(error)
            }

            let fileURL = ddir.appendingPathComponent(file + ".json")

            //writing
            do
            {
                if try dir.checkResourceIsReachable()
                {
                    var i = 0
                    var finalString = "JSON DATA GOES HERE..."

                    try finalString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

                    let text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
                    print(text2)
                } else
                {
                    print(dir.description + " is unreachable")
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error writing file: ", file)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some actual details? Instead of talking _about_ what you're doing, maybe show _what_ you're doing?

Comment: Thanks, Matt, added the code used to create the file.